# Apply Angular 4 validation dynamically on the basis of some conditions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to apply Angular 4 validation dynamically on the basis of some conditions, I am using Reactive form. This is my scenario,

I have an radio button: like this: `A: yes B: no`
If user select `"yes"` then a textbox(`formControlName="your_name")` will shown where user can add his name.
So, I want to add dynamic validation like if user select `"yes"` from radio than `"your_name"` should be required field otherwise not.

So how can I add dynamic validation here:

```
fb.group({
    your_name':['',Validators.required]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set validator using `setValidators()`.once the radio button is checked set validator by

`this.your_form_name.controls["your_control_name"].setValidators(Validators.required)`;

Comment: how to make on click of No, not required(means revert back validaiton) @Arun Kumaresh